# is there a way to know what Uri the apps on my phone connect to?

Tags: web-server

there's one app on my phone that i need to know exactly what Uri it uses to connect to it's server. is there a way to find out how?

tl:dr - i'm not trying to hack or damage, and actually the app is developed by the company i started work for, and the guy before me wrote the Uri, but as he removed the source code when he left. Now my boss has only said to me "find it", and now as i'm extremely new to server stuff, i see no other way to recover it other than finding out what uri the app uses.

Comment: By decompiling the app may be?

Comment: @esQmo no, that wont help in my current situation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. look for a software called wireshark
2. `easy way` look at your router maybe in
   the support options to capture the network traffic to the router. On android maybe this app [PacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture) `hard way` device in your network that can run wireshark with a network card that can run in the promiscuous mode and that can act as gateway for your mobile
3. open this capure file in wireshark
4. here you have many options to analyze the net packages i.E. `Statistics -> HTTP -> Requests`
5. you could export the result to maybe filter

[Wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205117/http-request-statistics-in-wireshark)

[Promiscuous mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004538/how-to-put-nic-into-promiscuous-mode)

Comment: This could be the basis of a good answer but to be really helpful you'll need to describe how to do this.

Comment: @SIMMORSAL ... what router model are you own?

Comment: I could get my hands on the uri by other means, but as this answer could be a good backup plan, i will mark it. And thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Android app on playstore like "APK EDITER" can do your work. It opens the source code of the app and you can get the URL .

Comment: and it if works, can you please give full details step by step on how to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks, but the app is a unity game, and the uri has been inputted in inspector, not directly in the codes.